# How to update Geodatabase point file table from Excel data using FME

Tags: spatial-database, fme-form, excel

I have excel spreadsheet with data that I want to load into a GeoDatabase point  table. The table already exists and I want to update the data not append. There is a unique ID to link the Excel data to the point file. When I use Joiner in FME or load data tool in ArcGIS it appends the data rather than updating.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your question to clarify whether your geodatabase table is stored in a file geodatabase (*.gdb) or an ArcSDE geodatabase (in Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc) or another geodatabase type, please?

Answer (score 1):

When using FME, rather than using a joiner factory open the properties of the the writer and go to the parameters tab.
In there change the writer mode from INSERT to UPDATE.  Then set your unique key field in the Update Key Columns field.  Here's a link that may help [Editing Writer Properties](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Workbench/Default.htm#editing_writer_feature_type_properties.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%20Workbench%7CFeature%20Types%20and%20Attributes%7C_____5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes to MickyT's answer - and also the DatabaseUpdater transformer might be of use.

Also, there's an FME Tutorial on Spatial Databases at: http://www.safe.com/learning/training/on-demand/tutorials/ which I happen to know covers updates.